# Decay Rate of Fourier like Integral

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, asymptotics

I'm trying to investigate the decay of Legrende coefficients for the polynomials,

$$
P_k^d(t) = (-1/2)^k \cfrac{\Gamma(\frac{d-1}{2})}{\Gamma(k + \frac{d-1}{2})} (1 - t^2)^{(3-d)/2} \left(\frac{d}{dt} \right)^k (1 - t^2)^{k + (d-3)/2}$$

Using the approximation,

$$P_l^3(x) \sim \cfrac{2}{\sqrt{2 \pi l \sin(\theta)}} \cos((l + 1/2) \theta - \pi/4) + O(l^{-3/2}), \quad \theta \in (0, \pi), \quad l \to \infty$$

I'm interested in the decay rate of,

$$
\mu_k = \int_{-1}^1 \kappa(t) P_{k}^d(t) (1-t^2)^{(d-3)/2} dt
$$

Where $\kappa$ is known to be infinitely differentiable on $(-1,1)$, but not periodic. I'm aware of the Riemann Lebesgue lemma, but when I use the approximation for $d = 3$ I get,

$$
\mu_k \sim -\int_{0}^{\pi} \kappa(\cos(\theta)) \sqrt{\cfrac{2 \sin(\theta)}{ \pi l}} \cos((l + 1/2) \theta - \pi/4) d \theta, \quad l \to \infty$$

It seems like I'm still pretty far away from what I want. Directly applying Riemann-Lebesgue seems wrong. The right-term actually integrates to zero when $\kappa = 1$, but if we have $\kappa(t) = p(t) + t^\nu$ for some fractional $\nu$ near zero (or the similar condition near one) I want to know what happens. I'm specifically looking for an asymptotic rate that integral decay of the form $\mu_k \sim l^{-c}$.